# Placing Integer or String inside of 2D array at certain co-ordinates?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int, 2d

Trying to place either an integer or a string into an 2D char array, but I'm having no luck. Tried converting the integer to a string and then placing it inside the array, but not even sure if that works. And as a relatively new programmer, I can't think of any other way to insert the integer into the array, so any help would be great! Here's the portion of the 2D array below, I want to place an integer at '*ScoreInt*', I have the variable set up in a class if that's of any help.

```
Level::Level(Snake *s, Item *i)

/// TITLE SECTION

for(int y=1; y<8 ; y++)
{
    map[y][0]=' ';

    for(int x=1; x<70 ; x++)
    {
        ///Letter 'S'

        map[y][x]=' ';
        map[2][19]= 177;
        map[2][20]= 176;
        map[2][21]= 176;
        map[2][22]= 176;
        map[2][23]= 177;
        map[3][19]= 176;
        map[4][19]= 178;
        map[4][20]= 176;
        map[4][21]= 176;
        map[4][22]= 178;
        map[4][23]= 177;
        map[5][23]= 176;
        map[6][23]= 176;
        map[6][22]= 177;
        map[6][21]= 177;
        map[6][20]= 176;
        map[6][19]= 178;

        ///Letter 'N'

        map[2][26]= 178;
        map[3][26]= 178;
        map[4][26]= 176;
        map[5][26]= 177;
        map[6][26]= 176;
        map[2][27]= 176;
        map[3][27]= 177;
        map[4][28]= 176;
        map[5][29]= 176;
        map[6][29]= 177;
        map[2][30]= 176;
        map[3][30]= 176;
        map[4][30]= 178;
        map[5][30]= 176;
        map[6][30]= 177;

        ///Letter 'A'

        map[2][33]= 178;
        map[2][34]= 176;
        map[2][35]= 178;
        map[2][36]= 176;
        map[2][37]= 177;
        map[3][37]= 176;
        map[4][37]= 176;
        map[5][37]= 176;
        map[6][37]= 178;
        map[3][33]= 176;
        map[4][33]= 177;
        map[5][33]= 176;
        map[6][33]= 177;
        map[4][34]= 176;
        map[4][35]= 177;
        map[4][36]= 177;

        ///Letter 'K'

        map[2][40]= 176;
        map[3][40]= 177;
        map[4][40]= 176;
        map[5][40]= 178;
        map[6][40]= 176;
        map[4][41]= 176;
        map[3][42]= 178;
        map[2][43]= 177;
        map[5][42]= 178;
        map[6][43]= 177;

        ///Letter 'E'

        map[2][46]= 177;
        map[2][47]= 176;
        map[2][48]= 176;
        map[2][49]= 176;
        map[2][50]= 177;
        map[3][46]= 177;
        map[4][46]= 176;
        map[4][47]= 176;
        map[4][48]= 177;
        map[5][46]= 176;
        map[6][46]= 176;
        map[6][47]= 178;
        map[6][48]= 178;
        map[6][49]= 176;
        map[6][50]= 178;
    }
}

for(int x=0; x<71; x++)
{
    map[8][0]= 218;
    map[8][x]= 196;
    map[8][70]= 191;
}

/// INFORMATION SECTION (SCORE, LIVES)

for(int y=9; y<12 ; y++)
{
    map[y][0]= 179;

    for(int x=1; x<70 ; x++)
    {
        map[y][x]=' ';

        map[10][20] = 'S';
        map[10][21] = 'C';
        map[10][22] = 'O';
        map[10][23] = 'R';
        map[10][24] = 'E';
        map[10][25] = ':';

        map[10][27] = ScoreInt;

        map[10][40] = 'L';
        map[10][41] = 'I';
        map[10][42] = 'V';
        map[10][43] = 'E';
        map[10][44] = 'S';
        map[10][45] = ':';
    }

    map[y][70]= 179;
}

for(int x=0; x<71; x++)
{
    map[12][0]= 195;
    map[12][x]= 196;
    map[12][70]= 180;
}

/// GAME SECTION

for(int y=13; y<42 ; y++)
{
    map[y][0]= 179;

    for(int x=1; x<70 ; x++)
    {
        map[y][x]=' ';
    }

    map[y][70]= 179;
}

for(int x=0; x<71; x++)
{
    map[42][0]= 192;
    map[42][x]= 196;
    map[42][70]= 217;
}

///FOOTER

/*for(int y=43; y<44 ; y++)
{
    map[y][0]= "FOOTER";
}*/

refresh_display = false;

lSnake = s;
map[lSnake->getLocation().y][lSnake->getLocation().x]=lSnake->getSnakeAppearanceRight();

lItem = i;
map[lItem->getLocation().y][lItem->getLocation().x]=lItem->getItemAppearance();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `char()` on the ints you have

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can put in a char array is a char.

char is an integral type, and relates a value to a character. For example, in:

```
char n = q;
```

n actually has a numeric value of 113 (assuming that you use ASCII).

when you add, say 67 as an integer to your char array (again assuming ASCII) it would display as C. This is because the char type transfers that numerical value to a character.

Type-casting will work for single-digit integers, like:

```
chars[x][y] = (char)myInt;
```

But will be messy if there is more than one digit in myInt.

Also, you would be unable to store the entire value of an int in a single position in a char array, as each digit of the int would require 1 'slot'.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
cout << (everything_up_to_map[10]25) << ScoreInt << (map[10][40]_onwards);
```

On whichever output stream you're using? This would allow you to just stick the int alongside everything else.

**EDIT:**

I had an idea. How about using a stringstream, place your int in, extract a string from the stream, then for each item in the string, cast it to char, then put each of these individual values, in order, into your array. I'm a bit busy atm, but will post a little code later, if I can.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure how I split it into two sections that are recognized as variables. I tried splitting them up in class but that may not be the right area to do it, any help on how?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is for outputting in a certain layout. What exactly did you try, and in what way did it not work? This kind of information really helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I went into where my map is stored in the class, and set up two variables that are both maps but obviously have different names, then using those two maps I tried to store the two sections so I could display the Score between the two sections, but had no luck with that, so changed my code back to how it was.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post as a new answer because it's a fairly different method. Here's that idea for using stringstreams:

```
#include <sstream>
//Your includes
//& other code
int scoreInt;

//This bit takes your int, and places in a string as a chars, rather than a value
stringstream ss;
ss << scoreInt;
std::string tmpStr = ss.str(); //A temporary string for the next bit,
                               //Now with added int!

char digits[maxDigits] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}; //Use the max number of 
                                                    //digits you have room for

//Take each digit from the string, put it in digits
//So you don't overfill your array accidentally
//This should automatically truncate the number
for(int i = 0; i < maxDigits; i++)
{
    digits[i] = tmpStr[i];
}

map[1stSlot][ForScore] = digits[0];
map[2ndSlot][ForScore] = digits[1];
//So on, so on.
```

Bear in mind that I haven't tested this, and will need adapting to fit in perfectly.